# Random Words Generator doesn't work with >50 words

Tags: javascript, html, performance, random

I want to make a Random Words Generator using JavaScript and HTML. I wrote some code (below) - it works with ~50 words, but doesn't work with ~5000 words. What could be the problem?

Can't find the solution in Google

```js
var quotes = [
  "One", "Two", "Three"
]

function newQuote() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));
  document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Quote Gen</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Simple Quote Generator</h1>
    <div id="quoteDisplay">
      <!--Quotes will display here -->
    </div>
    <button onclick="newQuote()">New Quote</button>

    <script src="javascript.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please define "Doesn't work"?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Doesn't work - I click on "New quote" on my website and no quote appears (if in java inputs I have ~5000 words). But when I have ~50 inputs - new quote appears

Comment: right, and do you see any error on the debug console?

Comment: Thats the error on the debug console:
Uncaught ReferenceError: newQuote is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):473)

Comment: There are actually error before I click anything:

DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://ogjohnapadlnifppcnknkhgbjpbnjplk/resources/content.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1

GET http://box5882.temp.domains/~experkf7/javascript.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)       (index):475 

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier   script-1.js?ver=1596726197:539

Comment: The first one is relevant. your function `newQuote` does not exist yet when you click the button. Im afraid theres nothing wrong with your code, and it's hard for someone else to debug this problem because only you're in front of it

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work OK here, maybe there's a problem somewhere else ?

```js
var quotes = new Array(500).fill(true).map((_,i) => 'word-'+i); 

function newQuote() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*(quotes.length));
  document.getElementById('quoteDisplay').innerHTML = quotes[randomNumber];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Quote Gen</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Simple Quote Generator</h1>
  <div id="quoteDisplay">
    <!--Quotes will display here -->
  </div>
  <button onclick="newQuote()">New Quote</button>

  <script src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am doing that in WorldPress. Can it be the problem with server? but for me it seems very low memory task to execute, isn't it?